# show image on hover just for the actual hovered element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

I have a set of divs built like this with `display:none;` on `.imageholder`:

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="imageholder">
    <img src="img.jpg">
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="imageholder">
        <img src="img.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
<!--and so on...-->
```

and this jQuery:

```
$('.parent').hover(
function() {
    $('.imageholder').fadeIn('slow');
},function() {
    $('.imageholder').fadeOut('slow');
}
```

);
When I hover the `.parent` div all related parent divs are displaying the image.

How can I make the hover state to work just for the actual hovered parent element?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function () {
    $(this).find(".imageholder").fadeIn("slow");
}
```

You can use `this` in the `.hover` callback to refer to the hovered (parent) element.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.parent').hover(function () {
    $(this).find(".imageholder").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jt6jK/1/) you can use .find() method for to point div.

Just like

```
$(document).ready(function()
                  {
                      $('.parent').hover(function() {
                    $(this).find('.imageholder').fadeIn('slow');
              },function() {
                   $(this).find('.imageholder').fadeOut('slow');
              })
                  });
```